# Binary Semaphore to synchronize an Interrupt with a task in FreeRTOS

Tags: c, microcontroller, uart, freertos

Hello everyone im doing my first steps with RTOS. Im trying to receive an amount of data using `UART` in an interrupt mode. I have a Display Task where the commands are being written to a global buffer, and i just created a `UART Handler Task` where i want to read the bytes. The problems im facing are.

1. The semaphore i use inside the `UART Task` is unknown, even though i declared it global in the main function, so the `xSemaphoreTake()` function has errors there. Maybe a helpful Note: the `UART Task` is in a seperated file.
2. Is my implemntation of the `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback` and the `UART Task` clean?

here is the code i wrote:

```
SemaphoreHandle_t uartInterruptSemaphore = NULL;
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

    void mainTask(void* param) {
        uartInterruptSemaphore = xSemaphoreCreateBinary();
        if(uartInterruptSemaphore != NULL) {
            // Display Thread with a 2 priority
            xTaskCreate(&displayTask, "Display Thread", 1000, &huart4, 2, NULL);

            // deferred Interrupt to be synchronized with the Display Task, must have a higher priority than the display task
            xTaskCreate(&UartHandlerTask, "UART Handler Task", 1000, &huart4, 3, NULL);
        }
        for(;;){
        }
}
```

the callback function i wrote:

```
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *uart_cb) {

    BaseType_t xHigherPriorityTaskWoken = pdFALSE;
    if(uart_cb->Instance == USART4) {
        xSemaphoreGiveFromISR(uartInterruptSemaphore, &xHigherPriorityTaskWoken);
    }
    portEND_SWITCHING_ISR(xHigherPriorityTaskWoken);
}
```

and the handler task:

```
void UartHandlerTask(void* param) {

    huart_cache = param;
    const uint8_t tmp = rx_byte; //rx byte is global volatile variable
    for(;;){
        if(xSemaphoreTake(uartInterruptSemaphore, portMAX_DELAY) == pdPASS) {
            HAL_UART_Receive_IT((UART_HandleTypeDef *)huart_cache, (uint8_t *)&rx_byte, 1);
            // write data to the buffer
            RX_interrupt(tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you cannot have your `mainTask` as a function _in_ `main`.

Comment: You probably need an `extern SemaphoreHandle_t uartInterruptSemaphore;` declaration in the file implementing the `UartHandlerTask`. But this must be done in a header file included by _all_ files that use the semaphore.

Comment: I don't see the whole file but something inside me can assume that your `Semaphore` variable is declared above main function and below the other function (not at top of the file) that's why you faced with issue number 1. Is it true or I'm wrong?

Comment: @koder It was actually outside but then i had a doubt and moved it. Okay the extern has fixed it. Thanks a lot! but does the compiler know that this is the same `Semaphore` called in the `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback()` ? anything to say over the issue number 2?

Comment: @NickS sorry to say but you are wrong. I have placed the Semaphore on top of the file before posting the problem and it didnt help. It is fixed now with the `extern` declaration. What's with the issue number 2?

Comment: What you want to achieve does not require use of semaphores.  Just get the ISR to store each received byte in a queue to be read by whatever task needs the data.  Don't over-complicate your life.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting a better handle on C before trying to use an RTOS.  This will also show you a better way of unblocking a task form an interrupt than using a binary semaphore: https://www.freertos.org/2020/09/decrease-ram-footprint-and-accelerate-execution-with-freertos-notifications.html